# Linux wildcard not behaving correctly

Tags: linux, shell, wildcard

I will be running a list of processes that will have the following naming conventions:

```
a_feed
b_feed
c_feed
...
```

I have written a bash shell script that will allow me to filter out the processes with these naming patterns. Please look at the one line in my shell script below:

```
ps -ef | grep -i *_feed | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2, " ", $8, " ", $10}'
```

For some reason, `grep -i *_feed` is unable to find any process that conforms to the pattern `*_feed`.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep users regular expression, in which * means `matches 0 or more times`, and not `any character`. 
You should replace it with `grep -i .*_feed`

Answer (score 1):

`*` need something in front of it.

Also, if you have a file with the pattern `*_feed` in your working directory bash will do wildcard expansion.

Use:

```
grep -i '.*_feed'
```

Comment: When I changed my command to what you suggested, I got the following in return:

14316   /bin/bash   alp/alp_feed
14318   ./alp/alp_feed
14344   /bin/bash

How do I get rid of the first and last processes from being displayed?

Comment: yes, `grep -i '.*_[f]eed'` will do the trick. it just finds the grep process.

Comment: hmm I tried that too, but the two "bash" processes are still being displayed. I would only like to see the "alp/alp_feed" process? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: skip the awk to see why ;) BTW you can search in awk in the process name, that would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

from grep man page:

> -G, --basic-regexp
>                 Interpret PATTERN as a basic regular expression (BRE,
>   see below).  This is the default.

so, by default the pattern would be regular expression.
in your example, you could use `grep -i ".*_feed"`

Answer (score 0):

I usually save the output of the list of processes in a shell
variable and then search for the matching lines as a new command.  This avoids needing a `grep -v` 
to remove the running `grep` command.

I also match the lines inside `awk` so that no `grep` is needed at all.  I think this is easier to read and understand:

```
p="$(ps -ef)"
echo "$p" | awk '/_feed/ {print $2, " ", $8, " ", $10}'
```